# System is overheating after upgrading to 20.04

Tags: 20.04, radeon, fan

After upgrading my machine from Ubuntu 19 to 20.04 LTS and it started overheating.

```
$ sudo tlp-stat -t
--- TLP 1.3.1 --------------------------------------------

+++ Temperatures
CPU temp               =    53 [°C]
Fan speed (fan1)       =  4683 [/min]
```

Comment: Try disabling tlp. I remember reading somewhere that it is incompatible with the latest kernel and not necessary anymore.

Comment: 53°C is fine. Fan speed is a little high. Show me `ps auxc | grep -i therm`. Also show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact make/model of your computer, and we'll check the BIOS. Do you have Nvidia? If so, what model, and what version driver?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is fine

````
$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +55.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:        +53.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:        +54.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
fan1:        3200 RPM```
````

Answer (score 0):

That is a normal temperature for your desktop or laptop. In generall all modern CPU's have a TJunction temperature (aka thermal throttling) around 100°C. That's when the hardware safeguards kick in to protect your cpu from overheating. On desktop the cpu can run comfortably around 80°C when under load. On laptops it's a little more complicated. It largely depends on the cooling design of your manufacturer. In general 60-70°C is a good temperature for a laptop under load. Most laptops will fail because of dust getting inside of components and overheating from poor design or over use. Any difference in temperature after the upgrade could be due to software compatibility or changes in ambient temperatures.

If you are still conecered about overheating than you should stress test your system to see if it's stable and to see how hot it gets when everything is running at max.

To do that you can install stress with:

```
sudo apt install stress
```

```
Description: tool to impose load on and stress test a computer system
 'stress' is a tool that imposes a configurable amount of CPU, memory, I/O,
 or disk stress on a POSIX-compliant operating system and reports any errors
 it detects.
 .
 'stress' is not a benchmark.  It is a tool used by system administrators to
 evaluate how well their systems will scale, by kernel programmers to evaluate
 perceived performance characteristics, and by systems programmers to expose
 the classes of bugs which only or more frequently manifest themselves when
 the system is under heavy load.
```

Make sure you don't run it for too long, it's not a benchmarking tool. It may cause your system to crash. Better to have everything closed when running it. After a few minutes you can see where your max temperature will be. You can use what you have been using to check temperatures or you can install

```
sudo apt install hardinfo
```

```
Description: Displays system information
 HardInfo is a small application that displays information about your
 hardware and operating system. Currently it knows about PCI, ISA PnP, USB,
 IDE, SCSI, Serial and parallel port devices.
```

You can do this just for fun too, but your system temperature is normal at 53°C on a desktop or laptop.